# How did Stritzke take the cash?

Tags: the-lost-room

In the series [The Lost Room](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0830361/), Harold Stritzke has the comb. The comb enables the user to pause time. When time is paused it's made clear that the owner of the comb cannot effect people/objects that are frozen.

[image]

Earlier in the miniseries Stritzke is shown in a 7/11 type store. He uses the comb and steals money out of an open cash register. Cash which would have been held down by pieces of plastic/metal in the till.

[image: Cashier till similar to this one]

So how did he do this? Is this a mistake?